# One-To-One Foreign Key

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a problem with One-To-One Foreign Key Relationship Mapping in my project.

User.java

```
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
public Role ro;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
public int user_id;
@Column(name = "username")
public String username;
@Column(name = "password")
public String password;


@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "username")
public Role getRo() {
    return ro;
}

public void setRo(Role ro) {
    this.ro = ro;
}

@Column(name = "enabled")

public int enabled;


public User() {
}

public int getUser_id() {
    return user_id;
}

public User(String username, String password, int enabled) {
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
    this.enabled = enabled;

}


public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public int getEnabled() {
    return enabled;
}

public void setEnabled(int enabled) {
    this.enabled = enabled;
}



@Override
public String toString() {
    return String.format(
            "student[id=%d, name='%s', age='%d']",
            ro.getUsername(), username, ro.getUsername());
}

}
```

Role.java

```
import javax.persistence.*;

@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_roles")
public class Role {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
public int user_role_id;
@Column(name = "username")
public String username;
@Column(name = "role")
public String role;

public User user;


@OneToOne(mappedBy = "ro")
public User getUser() {
    return user;
}

public void setUser(User user) {
    this.user = user;
}



public Role(String username, String role) {
    this.username = username;
    this.role = role;
}

public Role() {
}

public int getUser_role_id() {
    return user_role_id;
}



public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getRole() {
    return role;
}

public void setRole(String role) {
    this.role = role;
}



}
```

this is the error :

Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: com.company.project.models.Role, at table: users, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(ro)]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.getType(SimpleValue.java:431) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.isValid(SimpleValue.java:398) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.isValid(Property.java:225) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:595) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:265) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataImpl.validate(MetadataImpl.java:329) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:443) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:879) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    ... 22 common frames omitted

Comment: Try annotating all `@Column` and `@MappedBy` either on variables, or getters in your User `Class`.

Answer (score 2):

You should annotate all `@Column`/`@OneToOne` either on variable declaration or `getter()`s. That is why hibernate could not find `Role` in `class User`.

Comment: Thanks i have this problem now No identifier specified for entity: com.company.project.models.User. This is my code                             @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public int getUser_id() {
        return user_id;
    }

Comment: Are you sure you can't mix field and method annotations? I do agree it's bad practice to do so.

Comment: I am sure you can not do it for `@Column` annotation, not completely sure for mapping. Indeed bad practice. Thanks.